# Angular js : Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, cors

I am getting this error when I am trying to post data using $http.post() in Angular Js.

**Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at {{post url}}. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.**

This is my code :

```
var ionicAppControllers = angular.module('ionicAppControllers', []);

ionicAppControllers.config(function($httpProvider) {
    //Enable cross domain calls
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;

    //Remove the header containing XMLHttpRequest used to identify ajax call
    //that would prevent CORS from working
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
});


ionicAppControllers.controller('createItemCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.parts = [];

        $scope.add = function() {
            $scope.parts.push({
                id: '',
                code: '',
                description: ''                   
            });
        };
        $scope.submitItemForm = function(isValid) {
            if (isValid) {
                $scope.postdata = {};
                $scope.postdata.item = $scope.item;
                $scope.postdata.description = $scope.description;
                for (var i in $scope.parts)
                {
                    for (var j in $scope.parts[i])
                    {
                        if (j == '$$hashKey')
                        {
                            delete($scope.parts[i][j]);
                            //console.log(j);
                        }
                    }
                }
                $scope.postdata.parts = $scope.parts;
                console.log($scope.postdata);
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'URL',
                    data: $scope.postdata, // pass in data as strings
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}  
                }).success(function(data) {
                    if (data.success)
                    {
                        alert('sucess');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert('fail');
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        $scope.add();
    }]);
```

Comment: I don't know what is it...just written to remove error...

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with Angular . The Server application should enable or allow request generated from your Angular Application which is hosted or running on any machine . If your running your app in localhost. Use CORS extension for chrome. If its from other server . lets say www.example.com .

The server code must be changed nothing on the front end perspective .

Please refer this link.
http://enable-cors.org/server.html

Answer (score -4):

if you use ASP MVC and get jsonresult you must to add this xml code in web.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Did they mention anywhere they're using ASP.NET MVC?